# Curious about a cached old domain

Tags: seo, google, domains, cache

I am a bit curious about my new domain. I had a domain before, let's say `http://example.com/`. Before expiration of that domain, I bought a new one with the name `http://another-domain.com/`. I uploaded all of my content on the second domain, but now when I search in Google about some query related to my `http://another-domain.com/` site then I also find my old domain in the results.

Will this give a duplicate content error for my new domain or any other kind of penalty from Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases as your Google have really helpful facility in their Web Master Tools: 'Change of Address' (Tell Google when you move your site to a new domain). To be able to use this facility I trust you must verify your ownership of the domain (that’s a part of WMT site setup) - so it has to be completed before domain to expire.

Trust Google not care for duplicate content on sites. As example from long time we use area location targeted sites with almost equal content - placed on various domains and sub-domains.

Comment: my old domain will expire after 1 month, can i use `'Change of Address`, second thing i already made a permanent redirection[301] from my old domain to new one..

Comment: Trust you can, just register your old domain in Google Web Master Tools and complete the site verification steps (if not completed yet). Then look for 'Change of Address' option under the site's Configuration section inside WMT.

Comment: i tried but i got the error of restrict only for root level domain, but i have that verified with subdomain like http://blog.example.com, so i am not able to do the `Change of Address` can you please suggest any other alternative :(

Comment: Do you own the main domain? If yes, just register the main domain to GWT and verify it - then this must to work. If not probably will be best to wait until google find the old is dead and skip its record. I found [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_8615949_remove-subdomain-google.html) online, but I'm unable to tested it.